# Run Cron Job every 1 minute from now

Tags: node.js, cron

i have a cron job scheduled to run every one minute to ping my server, but now problem is that this cron job runs whenever minute starts, so if i schedule job at 14:05:50, it will fire in 10 seconds but if i schedule it at 14:05:00, it will run in 59-60 seconds, so what i want is, when i schedule it at 14:05:40, it should fire at 14:06:40, is there available crontab expression that supports this kind of scheduling or do i need to calculate current minutes and seconds manually and fill out expression like that

this is my current code, i am using "cron" library for nodejs

```
    let IManagedCronTask = new CronJob(
        "* * * * *",
        fn,
        null,
        false
    );
```

Comment: that's not really how cron works, if you need that functionality just use `setInterval(fn, 60000)` (hack, don't use if you intend to use pm2 clustering etc)

Comment: is there any other alternative, for example i am doing subscription and i need to do something every month starting when user creates account

Comment: round the subscriptions time down/up to closest minute, or when you do the query for all subscriptions you will have the seconds, do billing/whatnot then apply the seconds back to the date i.e reflect as if it was done at that time